# Elasticsearch - Post Data using Java 1.4

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using Java 1.4 and we would like to push data to the ELK stack.

I checked their site and googled and its mostly turning up artifacts/articles

that need more than 1.5.Are they any options since we cant change the current

java version installed.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Java SE 6 was released in 2006 and if I remember correctly the minimum version for Elasticsearch (first public release in 2010) even in the early days has been that.

The oldest docs available on the Elastic website are for [0.90](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/setup.html) and that is ancient. Even if you could run an older version, there are no docs for it, so you really don't want to go there.

While upgrading existing applications can be a challenge, it's still not possible to run new services on newer versions? Anyway, you need to get to Java 6 at the very least or rather 8 for current versions.